# Django - ChoiceField cleaned_data gets String instead of Integer

Tags: django, forms, integer, choicefield, cleaned-data

I have a form field called 'units' like this:

```
    units = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in range(1, 11)], help_text = 'Units: ')
```

When I do `form.cleaned_data['units']` I get a String instead of an Integer. 
How can I change the field to get the Integer?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I finally found the Field type `TypedChoiceField` , that will return Integer if coerced = Int.

```
    units = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in range(1, 11)], coerce=int, help_text = 'Units: ')
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly for me :)